# Not able to call actions from AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-redux

I have a react component which is bind to actions. I am calling an api from this component and I want that after the api is success then I should pass the response to the actions. Currently I am doing it like this

In success I  pass the response to my action which is setAuthToken

```
class LogInComponent extends Component {

    static contextTypes = {
        router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }
 handleLoginButtonClick() {
        let token;
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://example-backend.appspot.com/auth/login/",
            "method": "POST",
            "credentials": 'include',
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            "data": {
                "password": document.getElementById("password").value,
                "username": document.getElementById("username").value
            },
            success: function( response, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                this.props.setAuthToken(response.auth_token)
            },
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {
            token = response.auth_token
            console.log('check');
            this.context.router.push('/app')
        });

}

render(){
        return (
            <div className="LoginPage">
                <div className="login-page">
                    <div className="form">
                        <form className="login-form">
                            <input id="username" type="username" placeholder="username"/>
                            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                            <p className="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Request Username and Password</a></p>
                        </form>
                        <button onClick={this.handleLoginButtonClick.bind(this)}>login</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({setAuthToken: actions.setAuthToken}, dispatch);
}


export default connect(null, matchDispatchToProps)(LogInComponent}
```

And this is the data.js where I have all my actions and reducers

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

    const INITIAL_STATE = {
        list: [],
        selectedRows: [],
        currentItem: {},
        auth_token:null
    }

    const FETCH_LIST = 'FETCH_LIST'
    const fetchList = ()=> (dispatch)=> {
        dispatch({type: FETCH_LIST});
        fetch('/api/items?n=1')
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(data => dispatch(fetchListSuccess(data)))
            .catch(err => dispatch(fetchListError(err)))
    }


    const FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS'
    const fetchListSuccess = (list)=> {
        console.log('Received List: ', list)
        return {
            type: FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS,
            list
        }
    }

    const FETCH_LIST_ERROR = 'FETCH_LIST_ERROR'
    const fetchListError = (error)=> {
        console.error(error)
        return {
            type: FETCH_LIST_ERROR,
            error: error.message
        }
    }


    const SELECT_ROWS = 'SELECT_ROWS'
    const selectRows = (ids)=> {
        return {
            type: SELECT_ROWS,
            ids
        }
    }

    const SET_AUTH_TOKEN = 'SELECT_ROWS'
    const setAuthToken = (token)=> {
        return {
            type: SET_AUTH_TOKEN,
            payload: token
        }
    }

    const SET_CURRENT_ITEM = 'SET_CURRENT_ITEM'
    const setCurrentItem = (item)=> {
        return {
            type: SET_CURRENT_ITEM,
            item
        }
    }


    export const actions = {
        fetchList,
        selectRows,
        setCurrentItem,
        setAuthToken
    }


    export default function DataReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
        switch(action.type){
            case FETCH_LIST:
                return {...state, isLoading: true }
            case FETCH_LIST_SUCCESS:
                return { ...state, isLoading: false, list: [...action.list] }
            case FETCH_LIST_ERROR:
                return {...state, isLoading: false, hasError: action.error }
            case SELECT_ROWS:
                return {...state, selectedRows: [...action.ids]}
            case SET_CURRENT_ITEM:
                return {...state, currentItem: {...action.item}}
            case SET_AUTH_TOKEN:
                return {...state, auth_token:action.payload}
            default:
                return state
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error like this

[image]

Error after trying below solutions

[image]

Comment: `this` in the success callback is not the `this` you want it to be - try binding the success callback to `this`

Comment: then what should I do ?

Comment: Can you please post an answer showing that? I am quite new to this. Thanks

Comment: a similar thing to what you did to make `$.ajax(settings).done` work ... use an arrow function or alternatively, as I said, bind the success callback to `this` - you know how to bind, you do so in your code - you know how these things work, you don't need an answer

Answer (score 0):

jQuery callback 'success' `this` is not pointing to your react component

```
handleLoginButtonClick() {
    let token;
    var that = this; //Save a reference to 'this' using scope defined 'that'

   var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://example-backend.appspot.com/auth/login/",
        "method": "POST",
        "credentials": 'include',
        "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        },
        "data": {
            "password": document.getElementById("password").value,
            "username": document.getElementById("username").value
        },
        success: function( response, textStatus, jQxhr ){
            // Using 'that' since 'this' belongs to jQuery
            that.props.setAuthToken(response.auth_token)
        },

    /* ... */

    }
}
```

Comment: Gave me error saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Check my updates in ques. I added an image of error at the end

Comment: Did you checked the validity of your `response.auth_token`?

Comment: Yup seems that this comes from your `DataReducer`, trying to understand which line is breaking it. Can you highlight it or put it under a breakpoint and add a screenshot or any indication?